# PostgreSQL advanced records counting

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE survey_results (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    scores jsonb DEFAULT '{}'::jsonb,
    created_at timestamp without time zone,
    updated_at timestamp without time zone  
);

INSERT INTO survey_results (id, scores, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (1, '{"medic": { "categories": { "motivation": "high" } } }', '2017-10-01', '2017-10-01');

INSERT INTO survey_results (id, scores, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (2, '{"medic": { "categories": { "motivation": "medium" } } }', '2017-10-02', '2017-10-02');

INSERT INTO survey_results (id, scores, created_at, updated_at)
    VALUES (3, '{"medic": { "categories": { "motivation": "low" } } }', '2017-10-03', '2017-10-03');
```

I'm getting data from this table with following query:

```
SELECT
  date(survey_results.created_at),
  json_build_object(
    'high', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('high'))),
    'medium', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('medium'))),
    'low', COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('low')))
  ) as motivation                               
  FROM survey_results
  GROUP BY date(survey_results.created_at)
  ORDER BY date asc;
```

which returns data in following format:

```
   date    |              motivation
------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-01 |    {"high" : 1, "medium" : 0, "low" : 0}
2017-10-02 |    {"high" : 0, "medium" : 1, "low" : 0}
2017-10-03 |    {"high" : 0, "medium" : 0, "low" : 1}
```

For example, if the date is 2017-10-01, should include all survey results captured from the beginning of time to the end of 2017-10-01. The second date will include all survey results that the first date did plus the survey results collected on 2017-10-02, and so forth.

So the results should be:

```
   date    |              motivation
------------------------------------------------------
2017-10-01 |    {"high" : 1, "medium" : 0, "low" : 0}
2017-10-02 |    {"high" : 1, "medium" : 1, "low" : 0}
2017-10-03 |    {"high" : 1, "medium" : 1, "low" : 1}
```

Here is the sql fiddle with schema and base query:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/61d7da/1

Is there any way for doing something like that in PostgreSQL?

Comment: so each day should consider the previous day or all the days that came before it?

Comment: Exactly, You're right.

Comment: If the attributes are always the same, you can extract them for each row and use `sum(...) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)`. Window functions are your friend.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Hmm could You show an example?

Comment: I did, but I won' t write the code for you. Look at the documentation for JSON functions. Perhaps a subquery is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
SELECT date(survey_results.created_at),
      json_build_object(
    'high', SUM(COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('high')))) OVER (ORDER BY date(survey_results.created_at)),
    'medium', SUM(COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('medium')))) OVER (ORDER BY date(survey_results.created_at)),
    'low', SUM(COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE (scores#>>'{medic,categories,motivation}' in('low')))) OVER (ORDER BY date(survey_results.created_at))
  ) as motivation                               
FROM survey_results
GROUP BY date(survey_results.created_at)
ORDER BY date asc;
```

That is, use cumulative sums.

As a word of advice, your queries would be easier to work with and understand without all the JSON object stuff.  You might want to get the query to just work and then add in the JSON formatting after everything works.

Comment: Thanks for reply, unfortunately this query not works, It returns: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "OVER" Position: 160`

Comment: @MateuszUrbański . . . I think the parentheses were in the wrong place.